# State updates on double click with react image mapper

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a [react image mapper](https://github.com/coldiary/react-image-mapper) library where I'm having a slight problem.

An initial circle is placed on my map, whenever I click on another area, the dot should move. I do this by updating the existing dot. What do happen is that I have to click on the map twice for it it move. I was thinking the library is ok and my function to update the state is incorrect?

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import ImageMapper from "react-image-mapper";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [mapAreas, setMapAreas] = useState({
    name: "my-map",
    areas: [
      { id: 5, shape: "circle", coords: [170, 100, 10], preFillColor: "#fff" }
    ]
  });

  const getTipPosition = area => {
    const obj = { top: `${area.center[1]}px`, left: `${area.center[0]}px` };
    console.log(obj);
  };

  const handleUpdateMapArea = useCallback(
    evt =>
      updateMapArea(5, [evt.nativeEvent.layerX, evt.nativeEvent.layerY, 10]),
    []
  );

  const updateMapArea = (id, coords) => {
    console.log(id, coords);
    const areas = mapAreas.areas.map(item =>
      item.id === id ? { ...item, coords } : item
    );
    setMapAreas({
      name: mapAreas.name,
      areas
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <ImageMapper
        src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4052/4503898393_303cfbc9fd_b.jpg"
        onClick={area => getTipPosition(area)}
        onImageClick={handleUpdateMapArea}
        map={mapAreas}
        width={500}
      />
      <pre>On each click, circle should be position of the clicked</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-image-mapper-qj5sl)**

I've tried not using `useCallback` but it's just the same.

Answer (score 0):

[This comment](https://github.com/coldiary/react-image-mapper/issues/32#issuecomment-559860336) has answered my problem.